# Blobstore - how to save data from a servlet

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I was looking over code google provided about how to save data on Blobstore. I need to save a large jason file. All the codes provided by google shows how to do it using a form.

I have a servlet, An android application will send the jason and the servlet will have to save that.

The DataStoreService class has a "put" method that does that but looks like blobstore does not have a "put" method.

Can someone please give me some example code that does this? Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can save data to Blobstore programmatically via the new [FileService API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).